# @importFrom or package::function in package development

Tags: r

When developing a package which of the following is best practice when using an imported function? Why?

```
#' @importFrom dplyr bind_rows
a_row_binder <- function(...) {
  bind_rows(...)
}
```

OR:

```
a_row_binder <- function(...) {
  dplyr::bind_rows(...)
}
```

Comment: The first ensures (when using `roxygen2`) that `NAMESPACE` is updated appropriately. If you maintain that file yourself, then I think it's mostly style. (I do both, personally, but that's for various reasons, none of them known to be required for package development.)

Comment: In the package development book, it is recommended to use `package::function` for specificity and readability. However, using importFrom has performance benefits (I think this is discussed in the Advanced R book). Either is approach is fine and it depends on what is easier to maintain. I vaguely recall one of the R books or a twitter thread saying choose one or the other when developing a package.

Comment: @r2evans What are your reasons for using both?

Comment: Mostly incomplete resolution of conflicts. For instance, when I import both stats and dplyr, `lag` and `filter` are conflicted. While the load order should be fine, during dev (using `devtools` to load instead of simply `library(..)`), I've found the repeated `load_all` and other things can cause one or the other to be masked. While I'm confident with a little more effort I could have resolved it, I chose at the time to just do both. No harm done other than a few extra characters (typed and stored). Not slower or unclear. Again, not "strictly needed", just something I did. @its.me.adam

Comment: @r2evans You could solve the conflicts by avoiding imports altogether and have a much shorter `NAMESPACE`. Why not go that route? Is it to improve the readability of your code?

Comment: That's a valid point, @its.me.adam